# Is it possible to create a custom screen GUI in Bukkit?

Tags: java, user-interface, screen, minecraft, bukkit

I'm wondering if it's possible to add some custom screen GUI's to my Bukkit server. So I can display a lot of text on someone's screen. Or do I need to find another option to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only practical way is to use an Inventory using blocks with name and lore for users to click on as can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qScVZhXum3Q)

Answer (score 2):

As [Cole Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8157656/cole-nelson) mentioned, a custom inventory with lore displayed might work. A [good guide for that](https://bukkit.org/threads/tutorial-create-a-inventory-menu.173571/) can be found on the bukkit forums, and although it's a bit outdated it should still provide useful information.

Another possibility would be to utilize title screens; obviously those can't hold a ton of information, but the player is pretty much guaranteed to notice them immediatly.

I recommend using [Title Api](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/titleapi-1-8-1-12.1325/), as it's a bit tedious to directly work with packets.
Once you added the jar to your project and set the dependency, simply use:

```
TitleAPI.sendTitle(player,fadeIn,stay,fadeOut,"Title","Subtitle");
```

to send a title with all corresponding attributes.

Example result:
[image]